# NUnit not looking the file in the right folder

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, nunit-3.0

I just updated nUnit from 2.6.4 to 3.0.1 on my VS2015. Everything went well with just ONE problem.

In my `Test` method, I have to load a xml file, let's call it `UnitTestConfiguration.xml`, it is saved inside the same root folder as the `app.Config` and `package.Config` file. With NUnit 2.6.4, this xml file is being found and load perfectly.

But, with Nunit 3.0.1, I receive this error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not find file 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\UnitTestConfiguration.xml'.

So my question is, why would 3.0.1 not look into the root folder of the test project to begin with, but somewhere else? Is there any setting(s) to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a [Breaking Change](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Breaking-Changes) in NUnit3, tests are no longer ran in the root folder.

Use `TestContext.TestDirectory` to reach it.