# moving levels up directory in nunit 3.2.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

After having some problem with nunit looking at wrong directory (specifically program files) I came accross this SO answer [NUnit not looking the file in the right folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35494833/nunit-not-looking-the-file-in-the-right-folder).

so `testdata = TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory` gives me the `Debug` directory of my test project.

so my question is if I want to access the root directory of my solution (say, I saved my test data file there) how do I navigate back from this Debug directory?

Answer (score 0):

You could just construct a new `DirectoryInfo` and walk up to parent directories. Something like this?

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory);
var testDataDir = dir.Parent.Parent;
```